# Error : Cannot read property 'updateProfile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app and I want to achieve this. When an user signing in I want to get his username and photoURL and store in firebase.

```
  handleSubmit=(event)=>{
    
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.isFormValid()){

    this.setState({errors:[],loading:true});

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
      .then(createdUser =>{
        console.log(createdUser);
        createdUser.user
          .updateProfile({
            displayName:this.state.username,
            photoURL:`http://gravatar.com/avatar/${md5(createdUser.user.email)}?d=identicon`
        })
        .then(()=>{
          this.saveUser(createdUser).then(()=>{
            console.log('user saved');
          });
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          console.log(err);
          this.setState({errors:this.state.errors.concat(err),loading:false});
        })
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({errors:this.state.errors.concat(err),loading:false})
      })
    }
  }
```

Can anyone have any idea about why I get this error?

output of Error and console.log(CreatedUser) :
[image: I received this type of Error]

[image: console.log(CreatedUser)]

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going wrong. Can you show the output you get from `console.log(createdUser);`?

Comment: `createdUser.user` is undefined mybe you should do : `createdUser.updateProfile` ,